# Selenium TimeoutException Error on clicking a button despite using EC.visibility_of_element_located().click() method?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to create an Account on Walmart using selenium python. I successfully  opened https://www.walmart.com/ and successfully go to **create an account** button under **Sign In** tab. Moreover, I also successfully entered the details of First name, Last name, Email Address and Password. However, once I clicked on ***Create account button***, I got **TimeoutException** error despite using ***EC.visibility_of_element_located().click ()*** method.

Can anyone kindly guide me what is wrong with my approach. Thanks in advance.

The source code of the website for **Create Account** button is as follows:

```
<button class="button m-margin-top text-inherit" type="submit" data-automation-id="signup-submit-btn" data-tl-id="signup-submit-btn" aria-label="Create Account, By clicking Create Account, the user is acknowledging that they have read and agreed to the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy">Create account</button>
```

My Python code is as follows:

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "https://www.walmart.com/"

first_name = "chuza"
last_name = "123"
email_id = "chuza123@gmail.com"
password = "Eureka1@"

options = Options()
s=Service('C:/Users/Samiullah/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/win32/96.0.4664.45/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source":
        "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
        "delete newProto.webdriver;"
        "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)
sign_in_btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Sign In']")))
actions.move_to_element(sign_in_btn).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space()="Create an account"]'))).click()

f_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'first-name-su')
l_name = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'last-name-su')
email = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email-su')  
pswd = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password-su')
f_name.send_keys(first_name)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
l_name.send_keys(last_name)
driver.implicitly_wait(1.5)
email.send_keys(email_id)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
pswd.send_keys(password)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
### 
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[normalize-space()="Create account"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this css selector that represent the desired webelement:

```
button[data-automation-id='signup-submit-btn']
```

and **xpath** would be:

```
//button[@data-automation-id='signup-submit-btn']
```

there are 3 matching nodes for each CSS and XPath and Selenium will look for the first match, the CSS and XPath basically are first matching node.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-automation-id='signup-submit-btn']"))).click()
```

or

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-automation-id='signup-submit-btn']"))).click()
```

It makes more sense to use `element_to_be_clickable` when trying to click on a web element instead of `visibility_of_element_located`. Also, CSS are much better locator as compared to XPath.

Answer (score 1):

`//button[normalize-space()="Create account"]` locator matches 3 elements on that page, you need to use more precise locator.
This locator is unique: `//form[@id='sign-up-form']//button[@data-tl-id='signup-submit-btn']`
So, this should work:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='sign-up-form']//button[@data-tl-id='signup-submit-btn']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

This *xpath* based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)...

```
//button[normalize-space()="Create account"]
```

...identifies three(3) elements within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and your desired element is the second in the list.

[image: walmart_create_an_account]

---

### Solution

The desired element is a dynamic element so to click on the ***clickable*** element instead of [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='sign-up-form']//button[normalize-space()='Create account']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of selenium, you can fix this by creating it manually, follow the steps:

Create an account on Walmart IO platform [here](https://walmart.io) by clicking on the man icon just before the search box.

Login to the account and accept "Terms of Use"

Click on "Create Your Application" to create a new application and fill in appropriate details.

You can follow [this tutorial](https://walmart.io/key-tutorial) to generate two sets of public/private keys -one set will be used for production and the other set will be used for stage.

Upload both public keys using this: `https://walmart.io/key-upload?app_name=<your app name>`

Consumer ID will be generated for both sets for prod and stage which can be seen on the [dashboard](https://walmart.io/dashboard)

Click on "Request Access" for OPD APIs at [here](https://walmart.io/docs/opd/) and fill out the form

Answer (score 0):

use the below code and replace "variable" and "idname"

```
variable = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="idname"]/button'))).click()
```

if that doesn't work right click the webpage, click inspect then use the arrow icon to click on the button that they want to interact with. after that the right click the source code of the button and hover over copy then click on copy xpath or whatever is needed